# Missing Authorization Header

Tags: iis, iis-6, iis-7.5, tridion

I have a website running an ISAPI filter providing SSO functionality, as well as anonymous & basic authentication.

The ISAPI filter populates the "Authorization" header of each request with basic credentials e.g. basic base64EncodedString (username:password), which I can see using Fiddler.

Next I have an HTTP Module picking up the basic credentials from the "Authorization" header, decoding them and placing the username in a new header value. The new header is then picked up by Tridion and used by the inbuilt SSO module.

This solution works in IIS6, but not in IIS7.5; in IIS7.5 the "Authorization" header is not present in the request. I checked for the header both in the HTTP Module, and in a dummy ASPX page.

Comment: It seems the IIS pipeline decodes the "Authorization" header and places the username in the "AUTH_USER" header. The next step of the issue is that, this header does not persist after URL Rewrite 2.0 acts as a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your ISAPI filter is not being triggered in IIS 7.5 then. Make sure that you have enabled them as described here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1178302.aspx

Comment: I can see the headers added by the ISAPI filter on each request. I think it maybe to-do with the order in which these events are happening.